# Printer keeps going offline in Windows 7 XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, printer, windows-xp-mode

Every time I reboot the computer, the printer in Windows 7 XP mode goes offline.  I have to go back into the full XP mode and attach the printer again to make it work.  I have the settings set to automatically attach the printer, but it doesn't appear to be working.  Any ideas what might make it automatically re-attach?  Does anyone see this working?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with Win7 printing to my HP6540 connected to a 98SE box and shared. Finally found the following post, look at the date! Thanks, Paul in Montreal!

Look here:
http://forums.techarena.in/vista-help/807020.htm#post3241524

> 20-10-2007
>   Paul in Montreal    Posts: n/a
>
> Re: Can't connect to Network printer - Win98
>
> ---
>
> Hello all,
>
> I've found a solution (worked for my setup) that clears the printer offline
>   problem when printing from a Vista laptop PC over a home network to a printer
>   connected to a Windows98 desktop PC. I never had this problem with my XP
>   Home laptop accessing the printers on the Windows98 PC.
>
> With the Vista PC, I was always able to Add my 2 printers (HP PSC 1350 and
>   Canon i560) using Vista's wizard (Add a local printer), but after a restart
>   of the Vista PC, both printers would be offline. In Printer properties,
>   Ports tab, both printers would appear as Client Side Rendering Provider under
>   the Description column.
>
> My Vista PC is a new Dell Inspiron 1420, Vista Home Premium.
>   My print server is a Dell Dimension V350, Windows 98.
>   Home network is WiFi using a D-Link 624 router, WPA-PSK security enabled.
>   Canon i560 on parallel port of Dell Dimension V350
>   HP PSC 1350 on USB port of Dell Dimension V350
>
> Here's the fix:
>
> 1. In Control Panel, Printers, delete offline printers. If they wont
>      delete, it may be because there are pending print jobs in the queue. Open the
>      printer and Cancel the jobs.
> 2. In Printer properties, Ports tab, delete the previoulsy installed
>      printers (offline statuts) that appear as Client Side Rendering Provider
>      under the Description column. To do this, highlight the port, then click on
>      Delete Port button. Click Apply.
> 3. Restart your PC.
> 4. Now reinstall the printers as follows:
> 5. Open Control panel, Printers, and click Add a printer.
> 6. Click Add a local printer.
> 7. Select the "Use an existing port" radio button, and select LPT1: (Printer
>      Port). Click Next.
> 8. Install the printer driver. Mine were found in the list inlcuded with
>      Vista. Select the manufacturer and the printer. Click Next.
> 9. In the next window, accept the printer name or type in a new name. Leave
>      the "Set as default printer" box unchecked. Click Next.
> 10. Vista should now install the printer. A window should open saying
>       "You've successfully added printer name.
> 11. DO NOT Print a test page at this time, because nothing is connected to
>       the LPT1 port on the laptop. Just press Finish. The printer you just added
>       should appear in the Printers window.
> 12. Click ONCE on the newly added printer to highlight it, then right-click
>       and open Properties.
> 13. On the Ports tab, click Add Portâ€¦, select Local Port, then click New Portâ€¦
> 14. When the Port Name window open, Enter a port name as follows:
>       \computername\printername
>       (replace computername with the name of your PC acting as print server, and
>       printername with the name of your printer). Click OK.
> 15. You should now have a new port listed on the Ports tab of the printer
>       Properties, but now the Description should be Local Port, instead of Client
>       Side Rendering Provider. Click OK.
> 16. Now you can go to the General tab, and Print a Test Page.
>
> Hopefully, your test page will print. Then restart your computer to check
>   that the printer comes back online.

Comment: In the Local Printer set up area, you can also create a new port, type is Local Port, then type in \\server\print_queue. Saves steps afterwards